# atan(c*tan(x)) does not consider x>pi/2

Tags: matlab, arguments

**The Problem:**

I have a problem in Matlab with a part of a function that calculates the value of

```
atan(c*tan(x)).
```

For some real c and x where x is an angle. Usually this would return some values between -pi/2 and pi/2 but I want it to mind "how often the angle got around": For example with c=1 we get the same result for x=pi/2 and x=3*pi/2.

This is what I want to avoid, in this case I would want it to calculate for x=3*pi/2 the value 3*pi/2 (I know that for c=1 atan and tan would cancel out, but for arbitrary real c they do not).

In other words, I want to make atan(c*tan(x)) continuous on R in x.

**How I tried to fix it:**

I simply added a function that kept an eye on the argument of the tangens:

```
atan(c*tan(x))+pi.*(floor((x./pi)+(1/2)))
```

This works for values that are not too near to the poles of the tangent function, but once x lies !very! near it breaks down (jumps of heigh pi are observed). This is especially a problem for my calculations as x is near enough one of the poles all the time.

**What still seems to be the problem:**

Imho the problem is that the tangens has a "much higher resolution" near its poles than the "floor function" making its jump too early/late for the correcting function.

**My question:**

Is there another possibility to fix this problem that is not sensitive to x lying near the poles of the tangent ?

Comment: I am not sure but i think your function (to fix it) is not right. If you say x=0. THis would result in (`atan(0)=0`) plus `floor(x./pi)+1/2)*pi)` this beeing `pi/2`. But you would need to return either `0, 2pi, 4pi,...`. Mind trying to change `floor(...)` to: `floor(2*x./pi)`

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple possible solutions for this problem. A simple one would be to use a special case for x near pi + k*pi/2, letting atan(c*tan(x)) = +- pi/2 depending on whether x is slightly smaller, or slightly larger, than pi/2 respectively.

```
function Out = ContTangents(In,RidgeParam)
InOverPi = In./pi; 
Rounded = round(InOverPi); 
CloseRounded = round(InOverPi+1/2)-1/2; 

ArctanResult = zeros(size(In)); 
IsCloseVal = abs(InOverPi - CloseRounded) < 0.00001; 
CloseVal = sign(RidgeParam*(CloseRounded-InOverPi)) * pi/2; 
NotCloseVal = atan(RidgeParam*tan(In)); 

ArctanResult(IsCloseVal) = CloseVal(IsCloseVal); 
ArctanResult(~IsCloseVal) = NotCloseVal(~IsCloseVal); 

Out = ArctanResult + pi*(Rounded + 1/2);
```

This solution appears to produce nice-looking curves, and as far as I can see it avoids discontinuities and singularities. At least, it seems nice when I run

```
figure, plot(ContTangents(-10:.001*pi:10,2))
```

Edit: Some parts of the function are modified. When running `ContTangents(pi/2-exp(-36),2)` (the problem value in the OP's example below), I found this very peculiar behavior. Is this a bug in Matlab?

```
K>> InOverPi<0.5
ans =
     1
K>> round(InOverPi)
ans =
     1
```

This could be worked around through redefining an own `round` function which doesn't fail at the point `.5-eps(.25)`. In fact, due to the entertaining behavior of floating point at the limit, you can't even define that number as such, but you have to proceed as follows.

```
format hex
(pi/2-exp(-36))/pi
ans =
   3fdfffffffffffff
-eps(.25)+.25+.25
ans =
   3fdfffffffffffff
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

This still does not work (though it seems like it). I am handling values of x that are much nearer to (pi/2) than 0.001. Try the following:

X=30:40;

X=(pi/2)-exp(-X);

plot(X,ContTangents(X,2))

to see what I mean. (ContTangents is your function from above)

Comment: I rewrote the code. Try it again. Note that in your example, you're running against the floating point wall `eps(pi/2)`. Try `diff(X) ~= 0`.